# Replace value in yaml if name : xxx with bash

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I want to change yaml file `value` based on `name`:

Example:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app1
      image: imageurl.com
      command: []
      env:
      - name: MONGO_HOST
        value: localhost
```

Here you can see we have added an env for mongo host. Now using `BASH` i want to change `MONGO_HOST` `value` based on condition like `if - name: MONGO_HOST set value: 172.16.87.98`

Comment: Install a YAML-aware tool like `yq`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sed requires knowing if there is indeed `MONGO_HOST` on that file so grep comes into the solution.

```
 if grep -Fq -- "- name: MONGO_HOST" file.yaml; then
   sed 's/^\([[:space:]]\+value:\).*/\1 172.16.87.98/' file.yaml
 fi
```

The if-statement is from the shell, which checks if grep really found a pattern/regexp and execute `sed` in this case.

The `-F` means grep is looking for fixed strings, not BRE (basic regular expression) nor ERE (extended regular expression)

The `-q` means quiet or silence the output.

The `--` means end of options, because options usually starts with a dash `-` anything after the `--` grep will not treat it as an option anymore

If there is/are more than one string `value:` with the regexp  in that file.yml sed will replace em all. But as suggested already use the proper tool for parsing/editing yaml file.

Edit: as pointed out by `Ranvijay Sachan` sed can check if a pattern is there and replace the following line.

Using the command based file editor `ed`

```
printf '%s\n' '/MONGO_HOST/+1s/^\([[:space:]]\+value:\).*/\1 172.16.87.98/' ,p w | ed -s file.yaml
```

Comment: This will replace only next line i believe`sed -i '/MONGO_HOST/{n;s/^\([[:space:]]\+value:\).*/\1 172.16.87.98/}' file.yaml` and thank you for the solution i was looking exactly same.

Comment: Just one comment that it will edit yaml file if `- name: MONGO_HOST` string is found anywhere in the file not just in the previous line of `value:` string.

Comment: Indeed @anubhava

Comment: @anubhava the `ed` solution will only edited `in place` what is intended which is the next line after `MONGO_HOST`

Comment: Indeed, `ed` solution is very nice +1

Answer (score 18):

[kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) is a YAML syntax aware parser which uses `jq` as its JSON processor. `yq` takes YAML input, converts it to JSON, and feeds it to `jq`

The filter, the part under `'..'` is applied on the JSON object, and the resulting JSON with the IP updated is formed and it is converted back to YAML format, because of the `-y` argument.

```
yq -y '(.spec.containers[].env[]|select(.name == "MONGO_HOST").value)|="172.16.87.98"' yaml
```

Installation and usage is pretty straightforward which is available in [yq: Command-line YAML/XML processor](https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

You can use the in-place edit option `-i` just like `sed -i` to avoid re-directing to a temporary file with `yq -yi '...'`

---

##### mikefarah/yq

[mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) is a Go implementation of the YAML parser which since v4 has adopted a DSL similar to that of `jq`. So using the same, one could do

```sh
yq e '(.spec.containers[].env[]|select(.name == "MONGO_HOST").value) |= "172.16.87.98"' yaml
```

Comment: in my machine box if i type yq i see only eval and eval-all  commands only . how is this different from the above parser

Comment: @KishoreKumar: You have the `mikefarah/yq` installed then. The `eval` is abbreviated to `e` in my code above

Comment: So the `-y` option is used to retain to yaml format? I don't have this option in help

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '/^[ \t]*- *name: *MONGO_HOST[ \t]*$/{p=NR}
p && NR==p+1{sub(/value:.+/, "value: 172.16.87.98")} 1' file.yml
```

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app1
      image: imageurl.com
      command: []
      env:
      - name: MONGO_HOST
        value: 172.16.87.98
```

However, please keep in mind that it is usually better to use dedicated yaml parsers for this.

Comment: sed will require knowing if there is indeed `- name: MONGO_HOST` so sed alone can't do that.

Comment: @RanvijaySachan: awk is readily available on all Unix/Linux or on Windows. So suggest you to consider using that only.